# Calculate the number of days passed from a given year

Tags: java, datetime

I have this code for calculating the number of days passed from a given year:

```
for (int currentYear = localDate.getYear() - 1; currentYear >= STARTING_YEAR; currentYear--){
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(currentYear,5,5); //an arbitrary day of year
            jdn += date.lengthOfYear();
        }
jdn += localDate.getDayOfYear();
```

This code is working as expected.

I am not comfortable with choosing an arbitrary day to only get the length of the year. Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code scales poorly if there are many years between `STARTING_YEAR` and `localDate`.

Worse, if `localDate` occurs before the `STARTING_YEAR`, then your code behaves as if `STARTING_YEAR` is the same year as `localDate`, which is weird behavior.

To calculate the number of days between two dates, use [`DAYS.between()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalUnit.html#between%28java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.Temporal%29).

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS;

…    
long jdn = 1 + DAYS.between(LocalDate.ofYearDay(STARTING_YEAR, 1), localDate);
```

The `1 +` is necessary because the convention when subtracting dates is inclusive-exclusive, whereas your code uses an inclusive-inclusive range.